# Dos and don'ts during a pentest

Tags: penetration-test

I will be attempting my first real pentest as a junior pentester in a company (not a CTF). It will be on a web app.

For a first pentest do you think it is sufficient to just follow the OWASP Guide and just check the following list: [This list](https://github.com/OWASP/wstg/blob/master/checklists/checklist.md)? Is it the best methodology?

Plus I heard about a mistake that junior pentester make and it is using scanner from the start. I was planning to do that (going all out with sqlmap, crawlers etc.) but then changed my mind. Are there any other red lines like that?

Comment: You're a junior pentester, I guess there is also a senior pentester at the same company? Talk to them.

Comment: Already did just wanted some other advices and other pov @user253751

Comment: AFAIK there is not much wrong with using a scanner, the problem is when you ONLY use the scanner and then you do not find all the issues specific to this particular app and not detectable by the scanner which scans for issues that every app has. Another problem with scanners is you just copy-paste the scanner report instead of checking each report to see if it is actually a real problem

Comment: Unfortunately, this is too open-ended for a Q&A site. Answers will end up being a list based on people's experiences.

Answer (score 1):

There's no hard and fast ruleset. Personally, I prefer to go down the route of trying to use the website as a normal user would, browse around and keep track of things that look odd or interesting based on my previous experience. I then look into the things that seem the most interesting etc and go through the list. It's also pretty useful to note down the low-hanging fruit too like cookie flags and response headers.

Before you start anything, make sure you understand what is and is not in scope. Try to avoid straying out of scope as much as possible. If a subdomain etc not listed in the scope is used, ask if its usage should be included in the scope.

Having a passive scanner like the one found in Burp-suite (and probably other tools) is really useful for catching stuff that you might miss. Have a look at the list of extensions too because there are some good features there. (If websites keep logging you out it might be some overly aggressive extension, keeping that in mind can be useful for debugging issues.)

Make sure not to just trust issues that burp scanner or any other scanning tool outputs. Trust but verify (manually). It shouldn't take too long to pick up on which "findings" are normally false positives. That said specific tools are often fine. You don't need to manually test what ciphers are enabled if you ran SslScan for example. (It is useful to learn how to manually replicate the functions of tools but that can come in time with experience. You can start by just learning how to identify and weed out false positives.)

If you're stuck, confused, or feeling out of your depth, ask for help. Your colleagues have all been in the same "first pentest/new pentester" boat and will typically be happy to help. You're more likely to have positive reactions if you try to demonstrate that you had a decent go at something yourself, even if it is something entirely new to you. That said, don't spend hours trying to do something you don't get, have a good go, then ask for help. You're almost certainly somewhat-to-heavily time constrained.

Speaking of time... take evidence such as screenshots as you go. Ideally, report entire issues as you go, though if you prefer to report at the end make sure to take notes. Try to avoid rabbit holes, or at least come back to them once you're confident that you've covered everything else well.

Keep some sort of logical file structure for sorting your data within each and across all tests. Whatever works for you. Just make sure that if in 10 months' time, someone asks you a question about any test you've performed you can easily find the relevant data. Ideally, also use a format where you can delete really old data once it's reached your company's data retention time frame. A logical structure (especially if you keep your naming scheme simple) will help you in the long run.

A bit before the end of the test make sure you've covered the basics. OWASP top ten is a good place to start. Check your notes to see if there's something you wanted to look at that you haven't. Check your evidence to ensure that you have all the evidence you need to report (or that you can gather it offline, i.e from proxy logs etc).

Write a good and detailed report. Make sure to keep things professional and accurate. The report is the only part the client really sees. You'll often need a high-level overview and will always need a detailed breakdown. If you're not confident about why an issue is an issue or how it should be resolved, Google is your friend, if that doesn't work your colleagues should be able to help.

A good way to learn about reporting and techniques is to actively participate in a peer review process (assuming your company has something along these lines). If not, looking through reports from other testers essentially does the same. Doing so doesn't just expand your knowledge but also familiarises you with how your colleagues do things, which can help you fit in.